# Rails ActiveAdmin set value after submitting form

Tags: ruby

I have a form for Table1 which has a has_many relation to Table2.
In app/admin/table1.rb, I have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Table1 do
.
.
.
controller do
  def create
      .
      .
      .
    super
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
permit_params :xxx,
               .
               .
               .
               table2_attributes: Table2::ATTRIBUTES,
form partial: "admin/accounts/shared/new_and_edit_form"
end
```

Table2 has attribute1, attribute2, and attribute3 which is listed in ATTRIBUTES constant in its model file. I need to set attribute3 to true before calling super in the create&update method but I don't know how. I tried:

```
def create
  .
  .
  .
  table2_attr = params[:table1][:table2_attributes]
  if not table2_attr.nil?
    table2_attr.each do |attr|
      attr2[:attribute3] = true
    end
  end
  super
end
```

But when I submit the form it says no implicit conversion from Symbol to Integer

How can I set the value? I tried putting f.input :attribute3, as: :hidden too but I don't know how to set the value there also.
Thank you

Comment: Can you post the output of params[:table1][:table2_attributes] please

Comment: {
    "0" => {
        "attribute2" => "2"
    }
}
@Mark attribute1 is foreign key to Table1 (which is ID of Table1)